# Heroku -- ImportError: No module named Crypto

Tags: python, heroku, flask, virtualenv, pycrypto

I am trying to deploy a Flask app via Heroku, but the app keeps crashing, and in `heroku logs`, I get:

> 2015-01-20T06:26:40.553579+00:00 app[web.1]: from Crypto import Random
>   2015-01-20T06:26:40.553639+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named Crypto
>   2015-01-20T06:26:40.553531+00:00 app[web.1]: from ZiggeoAuth import ZiggeoAuth
>   2015-01-20T06:26:41.333576+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
>   2015-01-20T06:26:41.340320+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed.

I've tried using virtualenv and gunicorn and also deploying outside of virtuanlenv, but the import error remains. Running `foreman start` runs without errors. The `requirements.txt` generated by `pip freeze` yields:

```
Django==1.6.2  
Flask==0.10.1  
Jinja2==2.7.3  
MarkupSafe==0.23  
MySQL-python==1.2.5  
Pillow==2.4.0  
PyRSS2Gen==1.0.0  
South==0.8.4  
Twisted==12.2.0  
Werkzeug==0.9.6  
altgraph==0.10.1  
bdist-mpkg==0.4.4  
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2  
bonjour-py==0.3  
cffi==0.8.6  
cryptography==0.7.2  
django-twitter-bootstrap==3.1.1  
enum34==1.0.4  
itsdangerous==0.24  
macholib==1.5  
matplotlib==1.1.1  
modulegraph==0.10.1  
numpy==1.6.2  
pep8==1.5.7  
py2app==0.7.1  
pyOpenSSL==0.13  
pyasn1==0.1.7  
pycparser==2.10  
**pycrypto==2.6.1**  
pyobjc-core==2.3.2a0  
... (other pyobjc things) ...  
python-dateutil==1.5  
pytz==2012d  
requests==2.4.3  
scipy==0.11.0  
six==1.9.0  
vboxapi==1.0  
virtualenv==1.11.4  
wsgiref==0.1.2  
wxPython==3.0.1.1  
wxPython-common==3.0.1.1  
xattr==0.6.4  
zope.interface==3.8.0
```

Something that might be important is that I manually installed [PyCrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) rather than using Pip, since it didn't work with any package managers. I'm wondering if it's a configuration or pathing issue, but I don't know how to check.
`heroku config` says that the app has no config vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: appended the flag `--no-site-packages` to `virtualenv`.

Comment: This may be old, but I searched long and hard to figure out why `foreman start` was not working, and this solved it. Thank you!